# dataTable - set export file name

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm using dataTable

Is it possible to set export file name to all file formats (with one command) or do i have to do it per every button?

If so - how do i set it to csv, excel and pdf?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dt_light4').DataTable({
    "paging":   true,
    "ordering": true,
    "searching":true,
    "info":     true,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'pageLength','copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
    });
});         
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve that using the buttons options.

Look at my example:

```js
var $fileName = 'MyFileName';

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
            extend: 'csv',
            filename: $fileName
            },
          {
            extend: 'excel',
            filename: $fileName
            },
          {
            extend: 'pdf',
            filename: $fileName
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="table display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>First name</th>
          <th>Last name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
          <th>Extn.</th>
          <th>E-mail</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <td>Tiger</td>
          <td>Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011/04/25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
          <td>5421</td>
          <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Garrett</td>
          <td>Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011/07/25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
          <td>8422</td>
          <td>g.winters@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Ashton</td>
          <td>Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009/01/12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
          <td>1562</td>
          <td>a.cox@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Cedric</td>
          <td>Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012/03/29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
          <td>6224</td>
          <td>c.kelly@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Airi</td>
          <td>Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008/11/28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
          <td>5407</td>
          <td>a.satou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brielle</td>
          <td>Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012/12/02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
          <td>4804</td>
          <td>b.williamson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Herrod</td>
          <td>Chandler</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2012/08/06</td>
          <td>$137,500</td>
          <td>9608</td>
          <td>h.chandler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Rhona</td>
          <td>Davidson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>55</td>
          <td>2010/10/14</td>
          <td>$327,900</td>
          <td>6200</td>
          <td>r.davidson@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Colleen</td>
          <td>Hurst</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>39</td>
          <td>2009/09/15</td>
          <td>$205,500</td>
          <td>2360</td>
          <td>c.hurst@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Sonya</td>
          <td>Frost</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2008/12/13</td>
          <td>$103,600</td>
          <td>1667</td>
          <td>s.frost@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jena</td>
          <td>Gaines</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2008/12/19</td>
          <td>$90,560</td>
          <td>3814</td>
          <td>j.gaines@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Quinn</td>
          <td>Flynn</td>
          <td>Support Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2013/03/03</td>
          <td>$342,000</td>
          <td>9497</td>
          <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Charde</td>
          <td>Marshall</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>36</td>
          <td>2008/10/16</td>
          <td>$470,600</td>
          <td>6741</td>
          <td>c.marshall@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Haley</td>
          <td>Kennedy</td>
          <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2012/12/18</td>
          <td>$313,500</td>
          <td>3597</td>
          <td>h.kennedy@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Tatyana</td>
          <td>Fitzpatrick</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>19</td>
          <td>2010/03/17</td>
          <td>$385,750</td>
          <td>1965</td>
          <td>t.fitzpatrick@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michael</td>
          <td>Silva</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2012/11/27</td>
          <td>$198,500</td>
          <td>1581</td>
          <td>m.silva@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Paul</td>
          <td>Byrd</td>
          <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2010/06/09</td>
          <td>$725,000</td>
          <td>3059</td>
          <td>p.byrd@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gloria</td>
          <td>Little</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>59</td>
          <td>2009/04/10</td>
          <td>$237,500</td>
          <td>1721</td>
          <td>g.little@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bradley</td>
          <td>Greer</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2012/10/13</td>
          <td>$132,000</td>
          <td>2558</td>
          <td>b.greer@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Dai</td>
          <td>Rios</td>
          <td>Personnel Lead</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>2012/09/26</td>
          <td>$217,500</td>
          <td>2290</td>
          <td>d.rios@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jenette</td>
          <td>Caldwell</td>
          <td>Development Lead</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2011/09/03</td>
          <td>$345,000</td>
          <td>1937</td>
          <td>j.caldwell@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Yuri</td>
          <td>Berry</td>
          <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>40</td>
          <td>2009/06/25</td>
          <td>$675,000</td>
          <td>6154</td>
          <td>y.berry@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Caesar</td>
          <td>Vance</td>
          <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2011/12/12</td>
          <td>$106,450</td>
          <td>8330</td>
          <td>c.vance@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Doris</td>
          <td>Wilder</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>Sydney</td>
          <td>23</td>
          <td>2010/09/20</td>
          <td>$85,600</td>
          <td>3023</td>
          <td>d.wilder@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Angelica</td>
          <td>Ramos</td>
          <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/10/09</td>
          <td>$1,200,000</td>
          <td>5797</td>
          <td>a.ramos@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gavin</td>
          <td>Joyce</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>2010/12/22</td>
          <td>$92,575</td>
          <td>8822</td>
          <td>g.joyce@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jennifer</td>
          <td>Chang</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2010/11/14</td>
          <td>$357,650</td>
          <td>9239</td>
          <td>j.chang@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Brenden</td>
          <td>Wagner</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>28</td>
          <td>2011/06/07</td>
          <td>$206,850</td>
          <td>1314</td>
          <td>b.wagner@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Fiona</td>
          <td>Green</td>
          <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>48</td>
          <td>2010/03/11</td>
          <td>$850,000</td>
          <td>2947</td>
          <td>f.green@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Shou</td>
          <td>Itou</td>
          <td>Regional Marketing</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>20</td>
          <td>2011/08/14</td>
          <td>$163,000</td>
          <td>8899</td>
          <td>s.itou@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michelle</td>
          <td>House</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>Sydney</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2011/06/02</td>
          <td>$95,400</td>
          <td>2769</td>
          <td>m.house@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Suki</td>
          <td>Burks</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>53</td>
          <td>2009/10/22</td>
          <td>$114,500</td>
          <td>6832</td>
          <td>s.burks@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Prescott</td>
          <td>Bartlett</td>
          <td>Technical Author</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/05/07</td>
          <td>$145,000</td>
          <td>3606</td>
          <td>p.bartlett@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Gavin</td>
          <td>Cortez</td>
          <td>Team Leader</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2008/10/26</td>
          <td>$235,500</td>
          <td>2860</td>
          <td>g.cortez@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Martena</td>
          <td>Mccray</td>
          <td>Post-Sales support</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/03/09</td>
          <td>$324,050</td>
          <td>8240</td>
          <td>m.mccray@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Unity</td>
          <td>Butler</td>
          <td>Marketing Designer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/12/09</td>
          <td>$85,675</td>
          <td>5384</td>
          <td>u.butler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Howard</td>
          <td>Hatfield</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/12/16</td>
          <td>$164,500</td>
          <td>7031</td>
          <td>h.hatfield@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Hope</td>
          <td>Fuentes</td>
          <td>Secretary</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>41</td>
          <td>2010/02/12</td>
          <td>$109,850</td>
          <td>6318</td>
          <td>h.fuentes@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Vivian</td>
          <td>Harrell</td>
          <td>Financial Controller</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>62</td>
          <td>2009/02/14</td>
          <td>$452,500</td>
          <td>9422</td>
          <td>v.harrell@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Timothy</td>
          <td>Mooney</td>
          <td>Office Manager</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2008/12/11</td>
          <td>$136,200</td>
          <td>7580</td>
          <td>t.mooney@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jackson</td>
          <td>Bradshaw</td>
          <td>Director</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>65</td>
          <td>2008/09/26</td>
          <td>$645,750</td>
          <td>1042</td>
          <td>j.bradshaw@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Olivia</td>
          <td>Liang</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2011/02/03</td>
          <td>$234,500</td>
          <td>2120</td>
          <td>o.liang@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Bruno</td>
          <td>Nash</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>38</td>
          <td>2011/05/03</td>
          <td>$163,500</td>
          <td>6222</td>
          <td>b.nash@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Sakura</td>
          <td>Yamamoto</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>37</td>
          <td>2009/08/19</td>
          <td>$139,575</td>
          <td>9383</td>
          <td>s.yamamoto@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Thor</td>
          <td>Walton</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2013/08/11</td>
          <td>$98,540</td>
          <td>8327</td>
          <td>t.walton@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Finn</td>
          <td>Camacho</td>
          <td>Support Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2009/07/07</td>
          <td>$87,500</td>
          <td>2927</td>
          <td>f.camacho@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Serge</td>
          <td>Baldwin</td>
          <td>Data Coordinator</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>64</td>
          <td>2012/04/09</td>
          <td>$138,575</td>
          <td>8352</td>
          <td>s.baldwin@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Zenaida</td>
          <td>Frank</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2010/01/04</td>
          <td>$125,250</td>
          <td>7439</td>
          <td>z.frank@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Zorita</td>
          <td>Serrano</td>
          <td>Software Engineer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>56</td>
          <td>2012/06/01</td>
          <td>$115,000</td>
          <td>4389</td>
          <td>z.serrano@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jennifer</td>
          <td>Acosta</td>
          <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>43</td>
          <td>2013/02/01</td>
          <td>$75,650</td>
          <td>3431</td>
          <td>j.acosta@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Cara</td>
          <td>Stevens</td>
          <td>Sales Assistant</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>46</td>
          <td>2011/12/06</td>
          <td>$145,600</td>
          <td>3990</td>
          <td>c.stevens@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Hermione</td>
          <td>Butler</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>47</td>
          <td>2011/03/21</td>
          <td>$356,250</td>
          <td>1016</td>
          <td>h.butler@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Lael</td>
          <td>Greer</td>
          <td>Systems Administrator</td>
          <td>London</td>
          <td>21</td>
          <td>2009/02/27</td>
          <td>$103,500</td>
          <td>6733</td>
          <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Jonas</td>
          <td>Alexander</td>
          <td>Developer</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>30</td>
          <td>2010/07/14</td>
          <td>$86,500</td>
          <td>8196</td>
          <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Shad</td>
          <td>Decker</td>
          <td>Regional Director</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>51</td>
          <td>2008/11/13</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
          <td>6373</td>
          <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Michael</td>
          <td>Bruce</td>
          <td>Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Singapore</td>
          <td>29</td>
          <td>2011/06/27</td>
          <td>$183,000</td>
          <td>5384</td>
          <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>Donna</td>
          <td>Snider</td>
          <td>Customer Support</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>27</td>
          <td>2011/01/25</td>
          <td>$112,000</td>
          <td>4226</td>
          <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: You can use the `title` option instead of `filename` if you want to specify both, the file name and the tile of the document itself.

For more information check this **[File Name](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/filename)**